# why is the "+" sign disappearing between PHP and Flash?

Tags: php

I am passing a string variable between PHP and flash, and the variable has "3+L-T" inside it.  When I echo it in PHP in a broswer, the plus sign shows up.  However, when i trace it in flash the + sign is replaced with a space.  So it reads "3 L-T".  I know i have the proper embedded fonts because i also traced a variable generated in flash with + sign and it works fine.

My code in PHP is

```
$pitchAlg = "3+L-T";
echo ("systemResult=$pitchAlg");
```

output:  systemResult=3+L-T

My code in AS3 is

```
pitchID = e.target.data.systemResult;
trace(pitchID);
sample="3+L-T";
trace(sample);
```

output:  3 L-T
         3+L-T

Any help is appreoiated.
Thanks, Chi

Comment: I don't know flash, but I know + is a url encoding for space. So that's probably related.

Comment: Did you try url encoding the string before sending to flash?

Answer (score 0):

URL encode it in PHP before you send it to Flash:

```
$pitchAlg = "3+L-T";
echo "systemResult=" . rawurlencode($pitchAlg);
```